# How to create a Loading Indicator or a Progress Bar in NextJS's App Directory?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, next.js, material-ui

I have developed a large web application with **NextJS 13**, the first version was using the **Pages Router**.

After completing almost the entire website, I managed to migrate to the **App Directory**.

This migration was not essentially to upgrade for some new routing features, but I wanted to change my SASS's Large compiled file imported in the _app.tsx for better website loading time.

Since the loading was quite a big issue for this project, I started using MUI with the styling of the each component, simply a CSS-in-JS solution.

But the problem I found with the new App Directory, is the router events, I had a progress bar indicator from the **next-n-progress** package, but now it doesn't work, the user clicks on a link and the app takes some small time to load the next page.

The problem is not an issue for SSR pages since I have put a **loading.tsx** file in the root of each page, but it persists for pages with client-side configuration.

Like the Home Page, Sign-in & Sign-up, etc.

I tried another package for the Progress Bar that supports the new app directory, but it is not showing up at all.

This is the component responsible for the Layout:
[GitHub Component permalink](https://github.com/yassine-ct/NTIC-Rabat/blob/0f015afa62fcbc463355f2dfca63c2b4a77910a0/client/app/providers.tsx)

Is there any way to create a new progress bar with this new NextJS 13 Update?

Comment: Maybe relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75311417/i-want-to-render-styled-components-by-server-side-in-next-13-how-i-do

Answer (score 1):

### UPDATE

I found that it is a common issue with the new Next.js 13 App Directory, and there are some open issues about it, including multiple problems encountered in the App Router Behaviors.

So, I managed to use next-n-progress, but I noticed that it only works by **USING LINK COMPONENT**, since it triggers the loading for the progress bar to appear, plus it has a benefit of prefetching all Links present on the view-port.

So, meanwhile, just keep using Link instead of Router.push for simple navigation cases.